# Duplication follows an UV sphere but rotates duplicates

Tags: dupli-groups

I have an idea of illustration that would explore the duplication around a sphere function. It should look something like this :
[image]

But I meet some problems. First of all, the boxes that are in the upper position tend to rotate on themselves. I have tried with ICO sphere but this doesn't help.

Please note that this happens with the setting: Duplication of faces (with or without the scale option). Please see the jagged pink line :
[image]

If I use the "Verts duplication", I don't meet this problem of oddly rotated boxes. But "verts duplication" doesn't serve my project as good as the "Faces duplication" because it leaves a lot of space between the boxes:

[image]

As I didn't find a good solution, I thought to "Make duplicates real" and then rotate and scale them by rows with the "Manipulate center points: individual origins" option. That's almost better.

Is there a better way?

And is there an option to deform my initial mesh box (the drawers) to fit the exact geometry of every face of the sphere that duplicates the box ? (so that it would become more trapezoid in the top of the sphere)

Thank you.

Comment: Did you unwrap both duplicates the same way? Because of you unwrapped them both with different settings or even didn't unwrap them, they both might have different results...

Comment: I didn't unwrap. I thought unwrap was for UV texture. And anyway, the problem with wrong alignement happens before I "make duplicates real". The only elements I could unwrap are the box or the sphere. And that doesn't seems to change something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ask me why but flipping the sphere's normals seems to solve the problem.
"Normal" normals :
[image: normal]
Flipped normals :
[image: flip]